# Create UNIX "special character" file

Tags: linux, character, udev

Suppose I want to create, in the spirit of /dev/zero, a file /dev/seven that produces the character '7' whenever it is read from. How should I go about doing something like this? Would I need to modify the kernel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you'd need to create a driver for that special character device.

For linux, I'd suggest you read [Linux Device Drivers](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) by Jonathan Corbet, Alessandro Rubini, and Greg Kroah-Hartman. (Chapter 3 talks about char drivers, but do read at least the first two chapters also.)

Comment: Okay. So I need the kernel source and a file that starts "#include <linux/kernel.h>", etc.?

Comment: You need quite a few things, I edited my post with a link to a great resource for that. BTW, if your question was only about linux, please retag it (replace unix with linux).

Comment: However, there is also the possibility of a [user-mode driver](http://lwn.net/Articles/232575/) for something like that.

Answer (score 1):

A device driver is not necessary, a fifo special file plus a user program generating the stream of `7` is perfectly able to provide this behavior.

You'll need about a five line shell script, all told.

Comment: For some reason, it seems like a bad idea to make a user program that just "while (true); do printf 7; done" into a fifo. Is my intuition off? Would it really not flood my memory with 7's, and only produce them in the event of a read?

Comment: @koschei: I think it will do nothing until a reader connected, then fill the fifo write buffer, then block until the reader makes some space in the fifo.  Although, it would be much more efficient to printf say a thousand characters into the fifo at once.

Answer (score 0):

There's a short example of creating a device driver for Linux here, which might help to get you started:

- http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/drivers_linux